# Exception with playing audio file by using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios

I used MPMoviePlayerController to play autio in local or url. When I first to play a information,I should download the file and play at the same time.Then the second time ,I can play the information from local if it existed.

Now I create a Singleton named PlayController to control autoPlay，play ，pause，stop By manually.
    If I choose a picture，it will autoplay the file consistent to the picture.If it can not get the playstatus，user should play it by yourself.I can clicked different picture to play the correct audio.

The problem I met is that when I clickked a different picture，sometimes the bug will jump as the uploaded screenshot.

**init the Singleton：**

```
-(PlayController*)initWithScenicspot:(ScenicSpot*)sp
{
    pauseimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ReadyPlay.png"];
    playimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ReadyPause.png"];
    if (![currentScenicSpot.scenicSpotId isEqualToString:sp.scenicSpotId]) {
        currentScenicSpot=[sp retain];


    self=[super init];
    if (self) {

        if(!pcontroller){
            pcontroller =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
        }

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(loginfo) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        detailView=[[DetailView alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        detailView._clickbutton=self;
        [self.view addSubview:detailView];

        self.view.frame=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        NSURL* ns = nil /*=[HelpTools returnSpotAudioServerPath:sp.scenicSpotId]*/;

        NSString *audioDiskPath = [HelpTools returnSpotAudioDiskPath:sp.scenicSpotId];
        NSString *audioServerPath = [HelpTools returnSpotAudioServerPath:sp.scenicSpotId];
//        NSURL* ns = nil;
        BOOL isNet = NO;

        if ([HelpTools isFileExist:audioDiskPath]) {
            ns = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioDiskPath];

        }
        else{
            ns = [NSURL URLWithString: audioServerPath];
            [self downloadAudio:sp.scenicSpotId];
            isNet = YES;
        }

        [self setContentUrl:ns isNet:isNet];
```

**set the audio path**

```
-(void)setContentUrl:(NSURL*)url isNet:(BOOL)isNetData
{
    if (isNetData) {
        if ([pcontroller respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)])
        {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handlePlayback:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

            [pcontroller setContentURL:url];
            [detailView.coloredplaybar setProgress:0 animated:NO];
            [pcontroller prepareToPlay];
        }
        else
        {
            [detailView.coloredplaybar setProgress:0 animated:NO];
            [pcontroller play];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [detailView.coloredplaybar setProgress:0 animated:NO];
        if (pcontroller.playbackState){
            [pcontroller play];
        }
    }
```

**update playstatus**

```
-(void)loginfo
{
        if (pcontroller.playbackState) {

            float playprocess=(float)pcontroller.currentPlaybackTime/(float)pcontroller.duration;
            [detailView.coloredplaybar setProgress:playprocess];
            if (pcontroller.playbackState==MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped||
                pcontroller.playbackState==MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused)
            {
                [detailView.playControllButton setImage:playimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else
            {
                [detailView.playControllButton setImage:pauseimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            [detailView.playControllButton setImage:playimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
}


- (void)handlePlayback:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = (MPMoviePlayerController*)[notif object];
    if ([theMovie loadState] != MPMovieLoadStateUnknown)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter     defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                            name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                                          object:nil];

        if ([PlayController getPlayer].loadState == MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK) {
            if (pcontroller.playbackState && pcontroller.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {
                [pcontroller play];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**debug**

```
com.apple.coremedia.player.async:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code = 1,address = 0X4)
```

**crash file**

```
Incident Identifier: 3CF84469-2C6A-42F8-8DB7-490A8BCB7FCE
CrashReporter Key:   3bb7c18d7a7efc7433f20023298207ebb260efd2
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         HorticulturalJinZhou [1761]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/6A4BA4E5-DDF6-4CF5-A9DC-685C2FE4B799/HorticulturalJinZhou.app/HorticulturalJinZhou
Identifier:      HorticulturalJinZhou
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-01-24 12:27:37.314 +0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000004
Crashed Thread:  10


![enter image description here][1]![enter image description here][2]![enter image description here][3]![enter image description here][4]
![enter image description here][5]![enter image description here][6]


Thread 10 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 10 Crashed:
0   WebCore                         0x3654b098 WebCore::TimerBase::setNextFireTime(double) + 116
1   WebCore                         0x36590862 WebCore::FrameView::layout(bool) + 106
2   WebCore                         0x365a8d32 WebCore::FrameView::updateLayoutAndStyleIfNeededRecursive() + 86
3   WebKit                          0x34e5e898 -[WebHTMLView(WebInternal) _web_updateLayoutAndStyleIfNeededRecursive] + 36
4   WebKit                          0x34e5e79a -[WebHTMLView(WebPrivate) viewWillDraw] + 74
5   CoreFoundation                  0x341157fc -[NSObject performSelector:] + 32
6   CoreFoundation                  0x3411648a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 146
7   CoreFoundation                  0x341157fc -[NSObject performSelector:] + 32
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3411648a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 146
9   CoreFoundation                  0x341157fc -[NSObject performSelector:] + 32
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3411648a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 146
11  CoreFoundation                  0x341157fc -[NSObject performSelector:] + 32
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3411648a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 146
13  WebKit                          0x34e5e746 -[WebView(WebPrivate) viewWillDraw] + 86
14  WebCore                         0x365a8a6a WebCore::TileCache::prepareToDraw() + 46
15  WebCore                         0x36c05270 -[TileLayer layoutSublayers] + 36
16  QuartzCore                      0x34ca5f92 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 210
17  QuartzCore                      0x34caa114 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 220
18  QuartzCore                      0x34ca9e50 CA::Transaction::commit() + 308
19  QuartzCore                      0x34ca9784 CA::Transaction::pop() + 120
20  QuartzCore                      0x34ca9704 +[CATransaction commit] + 28
21  MediaToolbox                    0x34f30bf0 playerremote_AddToPlayQueue + 356
22  MediaToolbox                    0x34f1c540 playerasync_grabAndRunOneCommand + 808
23  MediaToolbox                    0x34f1bfd2 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 42
24  CoreMedia                       0x320d7bc6 figThreadMain + 146
25  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32f5cc16 _pthread_start + 314
26  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32f5cad0 thread_start + 0
```

Comment: I have take aprt the audio control from view showed .Then it becomes easy to control the memory leaks